# how to get data from form serialize codeigniter controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I try to get data from ajax pass from front page to my controller but i got only string to my controller so how can i separate it one by one.

this is form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form" action="<?php print base_url() ?>insertCategory" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
          <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">name</label>

              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name='name' required class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Name">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">name</label>

              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name='test' required class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Name">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category Detail</label>

              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea id="txtEditor" ></textarea> 
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword3"  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image</label>

              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="file" name="img" required class="form-control" >
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->
          <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right submit">Submit</button>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-footer -->
        </form>
```

this my code ajax:

```
$(".submit").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
var data = $('.form').serialize();
var val  = $("#txtEditor").Editor("getText");
var page = "<?php echo $page ?>";
var url  = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>insertCategory"
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data:{ 
                "data"  : data
           },
            success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
});
```

and this is my controller:

```
public function insertCategory()
    {   
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')==1){
            $data = $this->input->post('data');
            var_dump($data);
```

and this my data respond by ajax:

```
C:\....\AdminController.php:308:string 'name=dsfdsfs&test=dfsdf' (length=23)
```

Comment: the global var $_POST?

Comment: it now work i want to convert it to object or array `name=val` ..

Comment: $_POST is a array

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead,

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

it is posted as same as post work

Comment: yes i get the same like this :`.........AdminController.php:308:
array (size=1)
  'data' => string 'name=dsfdsfs&test=dfsdf' (length=23)`
buy i want to get it one by one

Comment: i want to get name and test values one by one

Comment: @FirstProgramer do you know what a loop is ?

Comment: yes i know but when data post from ajax it convert to string so result is like this `string 'name=dsfdsfs&test=dfsdf'`

Comment: remove this line $data = $this->input->post('data'); and simply var dump that

Comment: i found problem because from when i post ajax i send multiple data `data:{ 
                "data"  : data
           }`

Comment: so all data convert to string only 1 line like this:`name=dsfdsfs&test=dfsdf`

Answer (score 1):

For reference, use this code below.

```
 type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $('.form').serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
       console.log(data);
    }
```

Use

```
 data: $('.form').serialize()
```

instead of

```
var data = $('.form').serialize();
data:{ 
    "data"  : data
},
```

Answer (score 0):

At the controller the contents of your form will be available in the `$_POST` array. So the "name" field on your form can be accessed with `$_POST['name']`.

That said, you will be better off using CodeIgniter's methods to retrieve this data.

For example:

```
$name = $this->input->post('name');
```

If, for learning purposes, you wanted to see everything "posted" to the controller this will do the trick.

```
public function insertCategory()
{   
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')==1)
    {
        $posted = $this->input->post(); //get all $_POST items
        var_dump($posted);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i know how to get data from post. but what i mean data post is like this `string 'name=dsfdsfs&test=dfsdf'` and i found the solution because from jax  `data:{"data"  : data }`. when i change to `data: data` is work find we should not send multiple values include form serialize() function.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. That string is how data is always sent from a browser to a server. Does not matter if you send it using ajax or by submitting a form. The server turns that string into items in the $_POST array. You do want the values of the form inputs - right?

Comment: no i dont mean where in put in controller, you can check this line `var data = $('.form').serialize();` at script ajax. serialize function get all data from form input values. i put it into data variable  `var data = $('.form').serialize();` when i used multiple data post from `data:{"data" : data }` serialize function convert all my data input to this style `'name=dsfdsfs&test=dfsdf'` only one line. when we post it to controller will get this form `data=name=dsfdsfs&test=dfsdf` so i mean problem is from i used multiple post data `data:{"data" : data }`. I should use `"data+": data`.

Answer (score 0):

use parse_str(); that can return array after parse string

```
public function insertCategory()
{   
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')==1){
        $data = $this->input->post('data');
        parse_str($data, $parseData);
        var_dump($parseData);
```